# Создание тени вокруг объекта

Tags: c#, wpf

Требуется создать эффект тени вокруг кнопки (желательно с возможностью настройки угла освещения).

Подскажите возможно ли это сделать стандартными средствами wpf или придется реализовывать это самостоятельно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<Button Content="Content">
   <Button.Effects>
       <DropShadowEffect/>
   </Button.Effects>
</Button>
```

Подробности в [статье MSDN DropShadowEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.aspx).